# JavaScript code working only in Chrome but not in Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I'n new to programming and I tried something in JavaScript and it worked well in Chrome. But It fails to work in IE, Firefox, Safari and Opera. Am I doing anything wrong with my code?

```
function hp(form) {
    var count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0, count7 = 0, count8 = 0, count9 = 0, count10 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q1[i].checked == true) {
            count1++;
        }
    }
    if (count1 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 1st Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q2[i].checked == true) {
            count2++;
        }
    }
    if (count2 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 2nd Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q3[i].checked == true) {
            count3++;
        }
    }
    if (count3 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 3rd Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q4[i].checked == true) {
            count4++;
        }
    }
    if (count4 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 4th Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q5[i].checked == true) {
            count5++;
        }
    }
    if (count5 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 5th Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q6[i].checked == true) {
            count6++;
        }
    }
    if (count6 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 6th Question");
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q7[i].checked == true) {
            count7++;
        }
    }
    if (count7 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 7th Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q8[i].checked == true) {
            count8++;
        }
    }
    if (count8 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 8th Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (form.q9[i].checked == true) {
            count9++;
        }
    }
    if (count9 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 9th Question");
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q10[i].checked == true) {
            count10++;
        }
    }
    if (count10 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 10th Question");
        return false;
    }
    answer1 = (form.q1.value);
    answer2 = (form.q2.value);
    answer3 = (form.q3.value);
    answer4 = (form.q4.value);
    answer5 = (form.q5.value);
    answer6 = (form.q6.value);
    answer7 = (form.q7.value);
    answer8 = (form.q8.value);
    answer9 = (form.q9.value);
    answer10 = (form.q10.value);
    var a = parseInt(answer1);
    var b = parseInt(answer2);
    var c = parseInt(answer3);
    var d = parseInt(answer4);
    var e = parseInt(answer5);
    var f = parseInt(answer6);
    var g = parseInt(answer7);
    var h = parseInt(answer8);
    var ii = parseInt(answer9);
    var j = parseInt(answer10);
    var c = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + ii + j;
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= "The selected values are "+"</br>"+a+"</br>"+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+ii+j+"</br>"+c;
    if (c <= 20) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 20) && (c <= 25)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 25) && (c <= 30)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 30) && (c <= 40)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 40) && (c <= 50)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 50) && (c <= 60)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 60) && (c <= 65)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 65) && (c <= 75)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    else if ((c > 75) && (c <= 90)) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "ABCD" + "</h3>" + "</br>" + "<IMG ALIGN='center' " + "SRC='images/img.png'>";
    }
    c = 0;
}
```

I tried this code in local host and i got my desired output in Google Chrome. When i tried the same page in Firefox and other browser, it failed to work. Only checkbox validation is working fine. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? right click - inspect element. firefox uses firebug, IE f12, etc?

Comment: Console is giving me this error

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: @AmarIlindra That would be an issue with the HTML encoding, what are you setting the HTML encoding as?

Comment: Based on that error, you're probably missing a tag in your HTML - unrelated to your JS. Make sure your HTML has a meta tag for encoding, like: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` ... In your JS, keep in mind "Don't Repeat Yourself." Your last several lines all do exactly the same thing regardless of the value of `total` - no need for all those else/if statements. Above, try to think of how you could create a function to take the count & run the for loop with a single block of code instead of 10. Use the console/developer tools in the browser to debug & track down issues. Keep at it! :)

Comment: even after adding <meta charset="UTF-8"> still same problem but this time console is error free. Any other suggestions?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I have noticed that Chrome is more forgiving when it comes to small errors. It is strange how you are not getting an error in the debug box at all...
But, a place I can see from reading the code is where you define the variables `a,b,c...` I recommend placing a comma after each. So, you get:

```
var a = parseInt(answer1),
    b = parseInt(answer2),
    c = parseInt(answer3),
    d = parseInt(answer4),
    e = parseInt(answer5),
    f = parseInt(answer6),
    g = parseInt(answer7),
    h = parseInt(answer8),
    ii = parseInt(answer9),
    j = parseInt(answer10);
```

Then here is where I think you have an error. You have `var c = ...` again after already defining `c`. So, try removing the `var` right there.